# Getting an index error while training machine learning model for spam detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, naivebayes

I am creating a spam detection ML model using Naive Bayes from scratch and for that i need the likelihood of all classes(or P(feature|not spam)). For that, I've created a function:

```
import numpy as np
def get_likelihood(term_document_matrix, label_index, smoothing=0):
    likelihood = {}
    for label, index in label_index.items():
        likelihood[label]=term_document_matrix[index, :].sum(axis=0) + smoothing
        likelihood[label]= np.asarray(likelihood[label])[0]
        total_count = likelihood[label].sum()
        likelihood[label] = likelihood[label]/float(total_count)
    return likelihood
```

And then I've implemented this function using the following call:

```
smoothing = 1
likelihood = get_likelihood(term_docs,label_index,smoothing)
```

But I seem to be getting this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\SUKHMAN\Desktop\Spam detection project\spamdetection.ipynb Cell 9' in <cell line: 2>()
  1 smoothing=1
----> 2 likelihood = get_likelihood(term_docs,label_index,smoothing)

c:\Users\SUKHMAN\Desktop\Spam detection project\spamdetection.ipynb Cell 8' in get_likelihood(term_document_matrix, label_index, smoothing)
  3 likelihood = {}
  4 for label, index in label_index.items():
----> 5     likelihood[label]=term_document_matrix[index, :].sum(axis=0) + smoothing
  6     likelihood[label]= np.asarray(likelihood[label])[0]
  7     total_count = likelihood[label].sum()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py:47, in IndexMixin.__getitem__(self, key)
 46 def __getitem__(self, key):
---> 47     row, col = self._validate_indices(key)
 49     # Dispatch to specialized methods.
 50     if isinstance(row, INT_TYPES):

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py:159, in IndexMixin._validate_indices(self, key)
157         row += M
158 elif not isinstance(row, slice):
--> 159     row = self._asindices(row, M)
161 if isintlike(col):
162     col = int(col)
...
--> 191     raise IndexError('index (%d) out of range' % max_indx)
193 min_indx = x.min()
194 if min_indx < 0:

IndexError: index (1499) out of range
```

Comment: What is `term_docs.shape`? It seems that it has fewer than 1499 rows, hence the error.

Comment: The output for this is giving me (1,80). How would i go about fixing this error?

Comment: The shape of that matrix should be (N, T) where N is the number of documents and T is the number of terms. And it looks like you're expecting N >= 1500. So how did you make that matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the entire issue, but as I don't have comment privileges this will have to do.
In your first code block where you define the `get_likelihood()` function, you don't have indentation. I don't know if this is the way you actually have it in your code, but if so it could be your culprit.

Comment: This is only my second post. How would i be able to give you comment privileges. Also, i think that the indentation is supposed to be as is.

Comment: You can't, I just need to hit 50 rep and then I can comment evrywhere, until then I can only comment on my own questions and answers